# Splitting file by columns

Tags: linux, bash

I know about cut command which can cut a column(s) from a file, but what can I use to split a file into multiple files so that each file would be named as first line in that column and there would be same number of produced files as there was columns in original file

**Example (edit)**

Columns are separated by TAB and can be of different length. I would like first file to actually have names of rows.

```
Probe File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt
"1007_s_at" 7.84390328616472 7.60792223630275 7.77487266222512
...
```

Also thing is that this original file is extremely huge, so I would want some solution that could split this in one run. That is not calling cut repeatedly

Comment: Do all columns have the same width? Is that something which should be autodetected too?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your input data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can do it with one line of awk:

```
$ cat test.tsv
field1  field2  field3  field4
asdf    asdf    asdf    asdf
lkjlkj  lkjlkj  lkjlkj  lkjlkj
feh     feh     feh     bmeh

$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { names[i] = $i }; next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i >> names[i] }' test.tsv

$ ls
field1  field2  field3  field4  test.tsv

$ cat field4
asdf
lkjlkj
bmeh
```

*Edited to include Tab separator courtesy of Glenn Jackman*

---

**Addition**

Removing double quotes from the fields:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { names[i] = $i }; next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/"/,"",$i); print $i >> names[i] }}' example.tsv
```

---

**Additional Addition**

Removing double quotes from fields, only at the start or end of the field:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { names[i] = $i }; next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i); print $i >> names[i] }}' example.tsv
```

Comment: Since the specification declares file is tab-separated, might want to use `awk -F '\t'`

Comment: Sorry, can you add a code which would remove double quotes from values. I'm not good with AWK

Comment: Is this the quickest way actually or will it still waste a lot of time opening and appending files?

Comment: Does it perform well enough for your purposes? How does it compare to `time cat filename > /dev/null`?

Comment: Stracing the operation on your sample file (with a few extra lines), shows only one open syscall per field and buffered writes. If you have a lot of fields, you might exceed the number of file descriptors it will cache.

Comment: I have 5372 fields and 22000 lines. It is slow (Only about 5% completed by now). I would want something faster. You think I Linux will allow me to hold 5372 file handlers if I implement it with C++ for example?

Comment: Your shell ulimit is probably set to 1024 file handles, you can increase that. The system max files possible is `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`. I'm not sure what awk would do, if you can read `C`, go have a look at the source. You could batch the fields to process, e.g. first thousand, second thousand, etc, and make multiple passes. Or you can leave it running and go to the pub!

Comment: Yes. That is what I've done for now. I left it on PBS system. I will check it on Monday.